# Power curve fitting with 4 components

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, regression

I'm trying to fit a set of data to a power curve of the form f(x)=a*(x+b)^c+d, is there a formula to determine the a/b/c/d components?

For example, if I have the following data:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 740 |
| 12 | 420 |
| 13 | 313.3333333 |
| 14 | 260 |
| 15 | 228 |
| 16 | 206.6666667 |
| 17 | 191.42857143 |
| 18 | 180 |
| 19 | 171.11111111 |
| 21 | 164 |
| 22 | 158.18181818 |

I'm expecting b = 10, and d = 100... is there a formula to derive a/b/c/d based on the data above, and the fact that I'm looking for a power curve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, added more info!

Comment: I suspect you expected $b \approx -10$ rather than $+10$.  You may also want to change your $21$ and $22$ to $20$ and $21$ respectively.

Comment: There are non-linear numerical optimisation methods but they are overkill in your particular example.  You could look at the fractional parts of your $y$ values for a clue as to $c$. Plotting $\log(y-100)$ against $\log(x-10)$ could tell you $c$ and $\log(a)$ from the slope and intercept.

Comment: Well this is just sample data... the I never know what data will come in, but I do know it's in the form of f(x)=a*(x+b)^c+d. I need to be able to find a/b/c/d given the data that comes in... is there a general way to fit the curve fairly closely?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. By _components_, you mean _parameters_. It's a $4$-parameter model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to use a specialised software for "non-linear regression". https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html This involves numerical iterative calculus starting from "guessed" initial values of the parameters $a,b,c,d$.

A non-usual method (shown below) isn't iterative and doesn't requires "guessed" initial values. But the criteria of fitting isn't the classical LMSE. Since no criteria of fitting is specified in the question this non-usual method is convenient.

[image]

[image]

If a particular criteria of fitting (LMSE or LMSRE or LMAE or other) was specified a software for non-linear regression would be necessary as well as "guessed" initial values of $a,b,c,d$. This is not always easy and sometimes leads to not convergent iteration. Instead of, the values obtained above would be very good initial values instead of "guessed".

General principle of the non-iterative method :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . The fitting isn't wrt the equation model but wrt a linear integral equation to which the equation model is solution. In the present case the linear integral equation is : $\int y\,dx = \frac{1}{c+1}x\,y+\frac{b}{c+1}y-\frac{c\,d}{c+1}x+$constant , with $S_k\simeq\int_{x_1}^{x_k} y(\chi)\,d\chi$ .

Comment: Nice thanks alot, this looks like this is exactly what I am looking for. It's going to take a while for me to put my head around this solution, but this helps me out majorly.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's mostly working very well, but I'm running into situations where the results come up as NaN. For example:

47232,
96512,
125952,
145536,
159616,
159616,
170240,
178304,
184960,
190336,
194688,
198528,
201728,
204544,
207104,
209152

Where x starts from 11 and ends at 27 for each y value above.

It chokes at X(k) = (x(k) - b)^c, where b = -11.976 and c = 0.275... when x(0) == 11, the result is NaN. Is this a limitation of this non-iterative method?

Comment: Can you post an example of data where the difficulty arises.

Comment: Ah I think part of the reason my data doesn't fit in some cases is because the the curve formula is slightly off... it's actually y(x) = a*(b*x-c)^d+e. Would the approach change alot with the new term?

I'm going through your paper, looks like it's exactly what I need but my university math is very rusty. Do you have it published in english? I'm using google translate but it's butchering the formatting. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: y(x)=A*(B*x-C)^D+E isn't a correct form of the equation because the five parameters are not independent. They are only four independent parameters. Non-independent parameters leads to infinity many solutions related one to another which disturbes the numerical calculus especially in the usual iterative methods . Compare to the correct four parameters equation y(x)=a*(x+b)^c+d the relationsships are : a=B^D ; b=-C/B ; c=D ; d=E .

Comment: I cannot say if a part of the reason your data doesn't fit in some cases is because the curve formula is slightly off. Possibly yes. But without your data in a bad fitting case one cannot help you to choose another slightly different formula (but of course with independent parameters).